# Returning item in recursive call

Tags: prolog

I have been trying to implement by own version of a sliding puzzle, and have been working with a smaller-sized puzzle (2 sized puzzle) before I expand to a large size.

The prolog code that I have created thus far is

```
move(1,2,0) :- true.
move(A,0,B) :- move(A,B,0),!,true.
move(0,A,B) :- move(A,0,B),!,true.
move(A,B,0) :- move(A,0,B),!,true.
```

For the 2-sized puzzle I have, a correct solved puzzle is given as 1,2,0. What I have so far returns works correctly in determining if a valid input gives the solved puzzle of 1,2,0.

What I tried to implement next is returning the set of moves that leads to a correct puzzle, and I have gotten it to work (although not fully).

I modified the code above to:

```
move([X|X],1,2,0) :- true.
move([X],A,0,B) :- move([left|X],A,B,0),!,true.
move(0,A,B) :- move(A,0,B),!,true.
move(A,B,0) :- move(A,0,B),!,true.
```

When I type move(Input,1,0,2) it correctly gives me [left] which is what I would expect however I don't know how to implement it so that it gives me the correct output for move(1,2,0) - [] and move(0,1,2) - [left|left].

I have tried different various edits to no avail. I would appreciate some help as to what I am doing incorrect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your state rep?
I can't seem to imagine it as a 2x2 puzzle. Yours looks like a 1x3 puzzle so i'm going to go ahead and assume that.

```
move([],1,2,0) :- true. % Don't need to move -> Empty move list
move([left|X],A,0,B) :- move(X,A,B,0),!,true.% -> make a move left, Followed by whatever moves you need from (A,B,0)
move([left|X],0,A,B) :- move(X,A,0,B),!,true.
move([right|X],A,B,0) :- move(X,A,0,B),!,true.
```

The head of your rule has to have [ThisMove|RestOfMoves].

Comment: Without commenting on anything else, all the `true`s in the original question and your answer do absolutely nothing. You can safely remove them.

Comment: I know. I just kept them because they're in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes a lot of sense.